# Rails rspec capybara - undefined method `sign_out' for #<Class:0x000000099a4b20> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

As part of a request spec I am tring to logout a user with:

```
sign_out @user
```

but I get the error

```
undefined method `sign_out' for #<Class:0x000000099a4b20> (NoMethodError)
```

Code:

```
require 'spec_helper'

include Warden::Test::Helpers

...

  before(:each) do
    @admin = Factory(:admin_user)
    sign_in @admin
  end

...
  context "When Admin users logout they are returned to the admin login." do
    before(:each) do
      sign_out(:user)
    end
    subject { current_path }
    it { should == new_admin_user_session_path }
  end
```

Comment: can you post the surrounding spec code?

Comment: What are `sign_in` and `sign_out`? Are you talking about [this warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden)?

Comment: It looks to me like a scope problem, i.e. `sign_out` is being called from a scope which doesn't have the method. What happens if you simplify the test into one `it` block and no separate subject block? i.e. `it "...." { sign_out(:user) ; current_path.should == new_admin_user_session_path }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, `devise` provides a `sign_out` helper, but `warden` provides a `logout` helper.

- http://rdoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/TestHelpers
- http://rdoc.info/github/hassox/warden/master/Warden/Test/Helpers

Just some quick googling, I'm no expert.